# Passing an argument to a powershell script to be used for the Test-Path -include option?

Tags: powershell

this is my first time asking a question so bear with me. I am teaching myself powershell by writing a few basic maintenance scripts. My question is in regard to a clean up script I am writing which accepts arguments to determine the target directory and files to delete.

The Problem:

The script accepts an optional argument for a list of file extensions to look for when processing the deletion of files. I am trying to test for the existence of the files prior to actually running the delete. I use test-path with the –include parameter to run the check within a ValidateScript block. It works if I pass in a single file extension or no file extensions, however when I try to pass in more than one file extension it fails.

I have tried using the following variations on the code inside the script:

```
[ValidateScript({ Test-Path $targetDirChk  -include $_ })]

[ValidateScript({ Test-Path $targetDirChk  -include "$_" })]

[ValidateScript({ Test-Path $targetDirChk  -include ‘$_’ })]
```

For each of the above possibilities I have run the script from the command line using the following variations for the multi extension file list:

```
& G:\batch\DeleteFilesByDate.ps1 30 G:\log  *.log,*.ext

& G:\batch\DeleteFilesByDate.ps1 30 G:\log  “*.log, *.ext”

& G:\batch\DeleteFilesByDate.ps1 30 G:\log  ‘*.log, *.ext’
```

Example of the error message:

```
chkParams : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'includeList'. The " Test-Path $targetDirChk -include "$_" " validation script for the argument with value "*.log, *.ext" did not return true. Determine why the validation script failed and then try the command again.
At G:\batch\DeleteFilesByDate.ps1:81 char:10
+ chkParams <<<<  @args
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [chkParams], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,chkParams
```

The full script is below. I have not yet added the actual code to delete files, because I am still working on accepting and validating the arguments passed in.

I have searched google and stackoverflow but I have not found a solution to this particular problem. I assume I am either doing something wrong with the code, or there is a better way to accomplish what I want to do.

Note:
I should mention that I also tried running the test-path with multiple file extensions outside of the script with no problems:

```
PS G:\batch\powershell> test-path G:\log\* -include *.log

True

PS G:\batch\powershell> test-path G:\log\* -include *.log, *.ext

True
```

Script:

```
# Check that the proper number of arguments have been supplied and if not provide usage statement.
# The first two arguments are required and the third is optional.
if ($args.Length -lt 2 -or $args.Length -gt 3 ){
    #Get the name of the script currently executing.
    $ScriptName = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name
    $ScriptInstruction = @"

    usage: $ScriptName <Number of Days> <Directory> [File Extensions]

    This script deletes files from a given directory based on the file date.

    Required Paramaters:

    <Number of Days>:   
    This is an integer representing the number of days worth of files 
    that should be kept. Anything older than <Number of Days> will be deleted.

    <Directory>:        
    This is the full path to the target folder.

    Optional Paramaters:

    [File Extensions]   
    This is the set of file extensions that will be targeted for processing. 
    If nothing is passed all files will be processed.
"@  
    write-output $ScriptInstruction
    break
}
#Function to validate arguments passed in.
function chkParams()
{
    Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
        HelpMessage="Enter a valid number of days between 1 and 999")]

    #Ensure the value passed is between 1 and 999.
    #[ValidatePattern({^[1-9][0-9]{0,2}$})]
    [ValidateRange(1,999)]
    [Int]
    $numberOfDays,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
        HelpMessage="Enter a valid target directory.")]
    #Check that the target directory exists.
    [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -PathType 'Container'})] 
    [String]
    $targetDirectory,   

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,
        HelpMessage="Enter the list of file extensions.")]  
    #If the parameter is passed, check that files with the passed extension(s) exist.   
    [ValidateScript({ Test-Path $targetDirChk -include "$_" })]
    [String]
    $includeList
    )
    #If no extensions are passed check to see if any files exist in the directory.
    if (! $includeList ){
        $testResult = Test-path $targetDirChk
        if (! $testResult ){
            write-output "No files found in $targetDirectory"
            exit
        }
    } 
}
#
if ($args[1].EndsWith('\')){
    $targetDirChk = $args[1] + '*'
} else {
    $targetDirChk = $args[1] + '\*'
}       
chkParams @args
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-Include` on `Test-Path` is a `string[]`. You probably want to mirror that definition:

```
[ValidateScript({ Test-Path $targetDirChk -include $_ })]
[String[]]
$includeList
```

And drop the `""` from there because they will force the argument to be a string and thus trying to match a file that looks like `` `foo.log blah.ext ``.

You also have to either put parentheses around that argument when calling the function or remove the space.

Comment: Thank you for the response Joey. If I'm understanding correctly I just need to add the brackets for my string definition and remove the quotes around the $_ variable. I did this, but I still get an error.

Comment: chkParams : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'includeList'. The " Test-Path $targetDirChk -include $_ " validation
 script for the argument with value "*.log, *.ext" did not return true. Determine why the validation script failed and
then try the command again.
At G:\batch\DeleteFilesByDate.ps1:81 char:10
+ chkParams <<<<  @args
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [chkParams], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,chkParams

Comment: If value for include was: "*.log, *.ext" than it couldn't work. Only first call is valid, still - do not understand why depend on $args instead of adding param () with mandatory parameters for whole script? Also: if files are absent nothing will be deleted, so I don't think that validation is necessary, Test-Path for folder should be IMO enough.

Comment: @BartekB, Thank you for the response. I am not sure I understand your question, but if you are asking why I used a function to check param(), it is so I can provide a usage statement to the person executing the script. I also recognize that if files are absent they will not be deleted, but how do I know that the person executing the script did not make a mistake and target the wrong directory? Checking to ensure files exist allows me to provide a message to alert the user nothing was done, so they can take appropriate action in the event of a mistake.

Comment: @Joey, I did try executing the script with the quotes as in: & G:\batch\DeleteFilesByDate.ps1 30 G:\log “*.log, .ext”. This did not work, however removing the quotes and the space did work: & G:\batch\DeleteFilesByDate.ps1 30 G:\log *.log,.ext so it appears the the addition of the brackets and the removal of the command line quotes and space resolved the problem, as per your edited response. Thank you!